# Oracle 11g Composite partition - Range | Hash

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I am trying to create a table and partition it by range then sub-partition by hash. But I am getting an error. I am doubt what is wrong in the script. When we do the range partition can we specify different number of sub-partitions for the hash, like below in my example ( partition OTHER_1 having a three sub-partitions while all other partitions having two).

CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTHOLDER_P (id INT, purchased DATE, OBJECT_TYPE  VARCHAR2(50), PHONE_NUMBER  VARCHAR2(50))

PARTITION BY RANGE (OBJECT_TYPE)
  SUBPARTITION BY HASH(PHONE_NUMBER) (

```
PARTITION PARTNER_1 VALUES LESS THAN ('||''''||'Partner%'||''''||')  TABLESPACE USERS (     
  SUBPARTITION sp1 TABLESPACE ABC,
  SUBPARTITION sp2 TABLESPACE ABC
  ),

PARTITION CONSUMER_1 VALUES LESS THAN ('||''''||'User%'||''''||')   TABLESPACE USERS ( 
  SUBPARTITION sp3 TABLESPACE XYZ,
  SUBPARTITION sp4 TABLESPACE XYZ
  ),

PARTITION OTHER_1 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)   TABLESPACE USERS (
  SUBPARTITION sp5 TABLESPACE KLM,
  SUBPARTITION sp6 TABLESPACE KLM,
  SUBPARTITION sp7 TABLESPACE KLM
  ));
```

Error :

`SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:

*Action:`

thanks

Regards,

Era

Comment: Please explain why the VALUES LESS THAN clauses are so complicated for the partitions.  What actual values are you trying to split on?

Comment: The complexity comes when dealing with apostrophe/single quotes. The below theory apply here. SELECT 'There' || '''' || 's Alan'  == There's Alan  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

trivial...

```
KLM,
   ^ that's the problem
```

**Update after comment:**

Check those single quotes. Its not clear whether you want them to  belong to your partitioning value, also the percentage sign. Maybe instead of

```
PARTITION PARTNER_1 VALUES LESS THAN ('||''''||'Partner%'||''''||')
```

that would do exactly what you want:

```
PARTITION PARTNER_1 VALUES LESS THAN ('Partner')
```

**Update after 2nd comment:**

I can only guess that you might be looking for something like that:

```
select '||'''||'User%'||'''||' from dual;

||'User%'||
```

However, it just doesn't make sense to use that as partitioning value. Please explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry. It's my bad of posting correct SQL. I corrected the query. Even without that ',' I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please refer my comment under main question. I am trying to dealing with apostrophe/single quotes. That is why here the complexity.

Answer (score 3):

Hash partitions and subpartitions should always come in powers of two -- 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 etc. -- or you end up with an uneven distribution of rows between them.

That aside, there's an example in the documentation of how to specify the number of hash subpartitions -- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin001.htm#i1006565

I can't imagine why you'd want to do that, though. Hash partitions are useful for improving performance of large equijoins, but that's most efficient when the joining tables have the same number of hash partitions/subpartitions.

Comment: Thanks David. I am not joining tables. Even after range partition I have a large chunk for each partition. So I decided to further sub-partition using hash. In my understanding which is correct and I am expecting a performance improvement. I am not clear why each partition need equal number of sub partitions.

Comment: Well I'm not sure why you'd have different numbers of subpartitions. How do you decide how many subpartitions to use per partition? Also, with what type of operation do you expect to see a performance improvement, and why?